# Right use of "to be"

Tags: word-usage

My problem is simple, is "to be" necessary in this sentence or not?

> Sociality provides various benefits in comparison to solitary way of
>   life. Whereas in most of species it is maintained by kin selection,
>   causing social structures **("to be"?)** founded by closely related
>   individuals, some recent studies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the "to be" in order to complete the meaning of the sentence.

If you write: "...causing social structures founded" you have to complete the meaning by adding the rest of the action. IE: "..causing social structures founded by closely related individuals /to be rare./to VERB"